How can I prevent local standard users from right clicking and deleting files on the computer?
How can I prevent local standard users from right clicking and deleting files on the computer?
I think on the individual files, I have to right click, go to security, advanced and add a Deny permission for the user to delete. Is there any way to prevent from deleting, lets say shortcut .exe files on the computer without putting these files into a separate folder.
Right now I see a delete in the right click context menu and doing so is deleting the file.

For what you are asking exactly, a shortcut on the desktop that cannot be removed, you can just place this shortcut in c:\users\public\desktop This way the shortcut will be accessible to all users, but only admin users can write to/delete from that folder.

Use the Group Policy Editor (GPO) to set access permissions to folders, such as making them read-only. Of course, if the user is an administrator, that person could change GPO to allow full access.
For shared folders, e.g., a folder owned by another user, or a folder on a network server, use the Properties dialog, Security tab, to set permissions. Of course, it might not be a good idea to share folders with executable files, such as Program Files.
For greater system protection, run in kiosk mode.
For ultimate protection, run for read-only media, such as a finalized DVD. Whatever changes the user makes during a session are lost after rebooting.
